# Adobe Illustrator: After a radial repeat, how can you recolor individual intersecting shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

When making a pattern of intersecting shapes with Object>Repeat>Radial, can this shape be divided it into individual segments that can then be colored individually?

[Shape Builder tool recognizes individual sections[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Pathfinder** tool: the **Divide** option.

[image]

That will divide up your shape into individual paths.

You can also still use the **Shape Builder** by just clicking in each divided area - this will convert it to it's own path.

Comment: You can also choose a color for fill while shapebuilder is activated this does not change color of objects but will color the area shapebuilt. This allows you to color and shapebuild in one go.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Grab the **Live Paint Bucket**, pick a color, and start clicking.

Pick a different color, click more.... Or use the left/right arrow keys with the Live Paint Bucket Tool active to cycle through swatches. When done click the `Expand` button in the Control Bar across the top of the screen.

Or... double-click the Shape Builder tool in the toolbar and tick the "Cursor Swatch Preview" option and do all the above with the Shape Builder Tool.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful.